# Can't start worker, No module named 'celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I try to include tasks in my webapplication but i can't start the celery work.

My project structure is the following:

> website/website --> init.py, settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py
>
> website/index --> init.py, celery_app.py, tasks.py

**Index** is my startpage where i want to run the tasks.

**index/celery_app.py** has the following code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('index',
         broker='amqp://localhost//',
         backend='amqp://',
         include=['index.tasks'])

 # Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
 app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
   )

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.start()
```

**index/tasks.py**:

```
from __future__ import  absolute_import
from .celery_app import app

@app.task
def test_func():
    print("Test Background Task")
```

When i want to start the worker with *celery -A index worker --loglevel=info* I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'.
I run the commandprompt in the index folder.

The other solutions in similar questions didn't help me.

Screenshot of my Packages: [image: Installed packages]

Comment: How did you install celery ?

Comment: I use PyCharm Professional and i installed celery with PyCharm

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your file structure. Your celery app should be on the same folder as settings.py

> website/website --> init.py, settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py, celery_app.py
>
> website/index --> init.py, tasks.py

and also in the init.py in the website folder should be having

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery_app import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

Comment: Hey argo. That was the first thing i tried. I changed my structure and added the code but i have still the ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: are you using django too?

Comment: Yeah my django app is working. I've added a screenshot of all my packages in the environment

Comment: Also your `CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'` needs to be fixed. You are using without any userid password. That might also be the issue

Comment: @NealMcBeal Could you type `pip list | grep celery` in the same terminal and see if you get celery mentioned?

Comment: Tried it before with a user. I've added a user to the rabbitmq server with username, password, host... but it didn't help. I still get the Error ModuleNotFoundError.... I try to solve this problem since last week....

Comment: Tried pip list | grep celery but i get an error that the command is unknown or wrong written.

Answer (score 1):

only write

```
    app = Celery(
    "SARyS",
    broker='pyamqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq.insertmendoza.com.ar',
    include=["SARyS.Apps.TaskManager.Tasks"]
)
```

Comment: Hey Nelson, your answer would be more useful for the others if you added more information: why would you define the `app` this way? What does this code mean and why do you think it solves the OP's problem? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

To install Celery

```
pip install -U Celery
```

or

```
pip install celery
```

To import Celery Library in Python

```
from celery import Celery
```

To Test if it works properly

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task

def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was the commandprompt. I couldn't use the "normal" commandprompt. Instead of the normal i opened the commandprompt of my conda environment and now it works.

For everyone who wants to know where you can find the prompt/termin:

> Open Anaconda Navigator --> Environments -->Select your Environment -->
>   Click on the Arrow --> Open Terminal and then navigate with cd (if you
>   use windows) to the location you want.